# Where to use "!", ";", "`"

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, diacritics, exclamation-mark

Where should I use the following symbols while writing something in English language?

1. `!` — exclamation mark
2. `;` — semicolon
3. ` — [grave accent](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/characters/#char0060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use `!` at the end of an exclamation such as, "The house is on fire!"

2) Semicolon is the hard one. You can use it to separate independent clauses, combining two sentences. For example, you could say "I started up a mountain; I didn't make it to the top," instead of "I started up a mountain, but I didn't make it to the top." A semicolon can also be used for separation in a list of lists that use commas.

3) ` is sometimes used in foreign characters, as in the French `è`. The apostrophe `'` is used to show contractions such as *didn't*, taking the place of one or more letters, or to show possession, as in *Bob's answer*. Possessive pronouns such as *your*, *yours*, or *hers* don't use an apostrophe.